# variable not getting passed from one function to another in the same javascript page

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run the `console.log` as follows in the `initialize` function defined in the code below:

```
console.log("Checking for Value_Of_Process_Type in Initialize Function ! :" +Value_Of_Process_Type);
console.log("Checking for Todays Date in Initialize Function ! :" +TodaysDate);
```

I get `undefined` for both the variables. However, I see the values of both the variables in the following `console.log` defined inside the click handler of `processEmployeeData` function:

```
console.log("Value_Of_Process_Type and Value_Of_TodaysDate are as follows :"+Value_Of_Process_Type+" and "+TodaysDate);
```

So basically, my variables are not getting passed from the function `processEmployeeData` to the `initialize` function. Is there any other approach I can follow to make that happen or anything wrong that I am doing?

```
function EmployeePage() {
    var self = this;
    this.employeeData = function (employee_number_) {

    // Initialize the page
    this.initialize = function () {

        var employee_number = AppManager.selectedData["employee_number"];
        console.log("employee_number By calling page:" +employee_number);

        var Value_Of_Process_Type = AppManager.selectedData["my_page.Process_Type"];
        var TodaysDate = AppManager.selectedData["my_page.date_value"];

        console.log("Checking for Value_Of_Process_Type in Initialize Function ! :" +Value_Of_Process_Type);  //outputs undefined here
        console.log("Checking for Todays Date in Initialize Function ! :" +TodaysDate);     //outputs undefined here             
    };


    this.processEmployeeData = function (collection_) {

       $("#myPanel").on('rowclick',function(event){
           row = event.args.rowindex;
           datarow = $("#myPanel").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
           var response = JSON.stringify(datarow,null,10);
           var Process_Type = datarow["processType"];
           AppManager.selectData("my_page.Process_Type", Process_Type);
           var  Value_Of_Process_Type = AppManager.selectedData["my_page.Process_Type"];
           var TodaysDate = datarow["date_value"];

           AppManager.selectData("my_page.date_value", TodaysDate);

           var Value_Of_TodaysDate  = AppManager.selectedData["my_page.TodaysDate"];

           console.log("Value_Of_Process_Type and Value_Of_TodaysDate are as follows :"+Value_Of_Process_Type+" and "+TodaysDate); // Prints the values
       });
    };
```

Comment: Can you remove all the code not related to your issue? A more minimal example would help

Comment: @DelightedD0D Done !

Comment: Where is AppManager defined?

Comment: That is a separate javascript file in the same folder.

Comment: It sounds like `AppManager` is defined outside of the scope in which this code runs. So, within this scope, `AppManager.selectedData["employee_number"]` is in fact, undefined. You likely need to declare `AppManager` in such a way that it is available in this scope, or pass `AppManager` to this function like `. initialize(AppManager);`

Comment: If we forget about `AppManager` for some time, how can I pass the value of `Process_Type` variable in `initialize` function which is defined in the click handler as follow `var Process_Type = datarow["processType"];` I am getting the value of `Process_Type` in console.log inside click handler.

Comment: P.S: I have used AppManager for accessing variables from `EmployeePage.js` to another ` .js` pages in the same manner as I am doing in the above code and hence I was trying to use the same concept in the same page.

Comment: Are you calling `EmployeePage.initialize` before the user clicks on a row in `"#myPanel"`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D In the code the `initialize` function is defined before the `.on()` method as shown above. Were you asking the same thing? I have placed `initialize` function before `onclick` handler because the data in the rows which user needs to click needs to exist in advance.

Comment: What I mean is, you seem to be setting the value inside the click handler like `AppManager.selectData("my_page.Process_Type", Process_Type);` ie the data is not set until the user clicks on the row. If this is correct and you call initialize before you click on a row, those values will in fact be undefined. Unless you set these elsewhere as well

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yes, you are right. Also, I believe I can't set  my variables like this anywhere else`AppManager.selectData("my_page.Process_Type", Process_Type);` because I need to get specific information related to user click (for a particular row). What alternative approach you think I can use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in Javascript act as another type of object, mostly. Therefore, you can assign variables to a function; In your case, changing your declaration to `this.Value_Of_Process_Type=AppManager.selectedData["my_page.Process_Type"];` should allow you to access it elsewhere in the function with `this.Value_Of_Process_Type`.

Comment: I tried doing that in `initialize` function and then accessing the value in console log using `this.Value_Of_Process_Type`, it still shows undefined.